# Inserting New line dynamically after finding specified string in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to insert next line dynamically after finding specified string in html ...

Ex.if i have a line like

```
"Additional values arecontaining html"
```

i need to insert next line after the string "are" and i need the above line like below

```
"Additional values are <br>containing html"</br>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [mcve]. When asking question you should also include your _failed_ attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace to achieve this as in :

```js
$('.title').html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace('Additional values are', 'Additional values are<br/>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title">jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library.</div>
<div class="title">Additional values arecontaining html</div>
<div class="title">JQuery gives versatility and extensibility.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace()` is the method you are looking for:

```js
var str = "Additional values arecontaining html";

var newStr = str.replace(/(are)+/g, "$1<br>")

document.body.innerHTML = (newStr);
```

Comment: `str.replace(/(are)+/g, "$1<br>")`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all,

I found a solution using jq.

> ```
>  "Additional values arecontaining html"
> ```
>
> ```
>  
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>         $("div").each(function() {
>             var getContent=$(this).text();
>             var newString=getContent.replace('Containing','Containing');
>             $(this).html(newString);
>         });
>     });
> ```
>
> ```
>  "Additional values are   containing html"
> ```